# Identifying which websites within IIS7 are using .net

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

I have a windows 2008 server running many websites under IIS7.

Is there an easy way to tell which of those websites are using .net/have .net enabled for use on them rather than having to individually look at each websites settings to tell whether they are static site only/asp classic only/mix with .net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the application pools.  By default IIS will create a new apppool for each site.  .NET can be configured at the apppool level.  So if you want to disable .NET entirely you can set the apppool to No Managed Code.